# Interfacing battery to fpga

Tags: voltage, level-translation

Is there any way to interface a battery with voltage range 0-5V to a fpga with ADC range at 3.3V while maintaining full input voltage range i.e 0-5V mapping on 0-3.3V. I have gone through the following methods

- Using Resistor divider
  cannot use this as there will be always a path for the battery to discharge through them
- Using a transistor as a switch or a diode clamp circuit
  with these methods the range of input gets reduced
- active opamp circuit
  the only other thing that remains is using an active opamp circuit :- this will require the use of external components . Are there any other methods to achieve the same ?

**EDIT**-- Can a transistor operating in linear region be used to achieve this  ?

Comment: Using a resistor divider is a very common way of achieving this.  The simplest way is to use high value resistors (but watch the ADC input requirements), if you have a spare pin you can use lower value resistors and "ground" the divider using an input pin.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a high-side switch, which is just a complementary MOSFET pair, to switch the battery connection to the resistive divider.  Then you can use lower-value resistors which will cause less ADC error, and you can have it only draw current when you're actually measuring the battery voltage.

High-side switches are available as a single component, or can be assembled from discrete parts (an N-ch MOSFET, a P-ch MOSFET and a few resistors).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhvl8v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: what is the need of resistor R1 and R2 ?

Comment: It's a voltage divider, to halve the 5V (max) input from the battery before it's fed to the ADC.  You could use a higher ratio, e.g. 2/3 instead of 1/2, to give more dynamic range but the difference is only 1.25dB and the lower ratio provides a little headroom.

Comment: The voltage divider is represented by  R3 and R4 . I want to know the use of R1 and R2

Comment: oops sorry, didn't really read your question properly.  They bias their respective MOSFET's G-S junction so that they are off by default. When you apply a logic level '1' to the gate of Q2, it switches on and pulls the gate of Q1 low, which switches Q1 on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a resistor divider of high value so that it doesn't overly discharge the battery then use a rail-to-rail op-amp like the AD8605 to buffer the voltage from the potential divider.

Or, you can use a P channel MOSFET to connect the battery to a potential divider and then onto your ADC. You'll need an enable pin to activate the P channel device via (typically) an NPN BJT.

Comment: Your solution is similar to that given by markt , isnt it.So battery voltage will be available at the pmos. When we give a enable to nmos it would pull the pmos gate to ground and turn it on.So the pmos will then connect the battery voltage to the resistor divider. Did i get it right ?

Comment: @user22348 you got the switchable version correct except I said NPN BJT but it doesn't matter of course; an NMOS will do the job just as well when controlling the PMOS transistor. Using 1Mohm resistors and an op-amp is still also feasible and you don't need to worry about enabling something prior to a measurement.